# ffmpeg "end mismatch" warning, jpeg2000 to video

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg

Trying to convert a directory of jpeg2000 grayscale images to a video with ffmpeg, I get warnings

```
[0;36m[jpeg2000 @ 0x55d8fa1b68c0] [0m[0;33mEnd mismatch 1
```

(and lots of

```
Last message repeated <N> times
```

)

The command was

```
ffmpeg -y -r 10 -start_number 1 -i <PATH>/surface_30///img_000%01d.jp2 -vcodec msmpeg4 -vf scale=1920:-1 -q:v 8 <PATH>//surface_30///surface_30.avi
```

The output is

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (crosstool-NG 1.23.0.449-a04d0)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/jklebes001/miniconda3 --cc=/tmp/build/80754af9/ffmpeg_1587154242452/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc --disable-doc --enable-avresample --enable-gmp --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvpx --enable-pthreads --enable-libopus --enable-postproc --enable-pic --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-version3 --enable-zlib --enable-libmp3lame --disable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-gnutls --disable-openssl --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libx264
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[0;36m[jpeg2000 @ 0x55cb44144480] [0m[0;33mEnd mismatch 1

[0m    Last message repeated 1 times
    Last message repeated 2 times
    Last message repeated 3 times
```

...

```
Last message repeated 73 times

Input #0, image2, from '<PATH>//surface_30///img_000%01d.jp2':

  Duration: 00:00:00.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A

    Stream #0:0: Video: jpeg2000, gray, 6737x4869, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc

Stream mapping:

  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (jpeg2000 (native) -> msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4))

Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

[0;36m[jpeg2000 @ 0x55cb4418e200] [0m[0;33mEnd mismatch 1

[0m[0;36m[jpeg2000 @ 0x55cb441900c0] [0m[0;33mEnd mismatch 1
```

...

(about 600 lines of "end mismatch" and "last message repeated" cut)

...

```
[0m[0;36m[jpeg2000 @ 0x55cb4418e8c0] [0m[0;33mEnd mismatch 1

[0mOutput #0, avi, to '<PATH>/surface_30///surface_30.avi':

  Metadata:

    ISFT            : Lavf58.29.100

    Stream #0:0: Video: msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4) (MP43 / 0x3334504D), yuv420p, 1920x1388, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbn, 10 tbc

    Metadata:

      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 msmpeg4

    Side data:

      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1

frame=    2 fps=0.8 q=8.0 size=       6kB time=00:00:00.20 bitrate= 227.1kbits/s speed=0.0844x    
frame=    5 fps=1.7 q=8.0 size=       6kB time=00:00:00.50 bitrate=  90.8kbits/s speed=0.172x    
frame=    5 fps=1.7 q=8.0 Lsize=     213kB time=00:00:00.50 bitrate=3494.7kbits/s speed=0.172x    
video:208kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.732246%
```

What is the meaning of characters like [0;33m here?

I thought it might have something to do with bit depth and color format.  Setting `-pix_fmt gray` had no effect, and indeed the format of the jp2 images is already detected as 8-bit gray.

The output .avi exists and seems fine.

The line was previously used on jpeg files and works fine on jpeg.  With jpeg, the output has the line

```
Input #0, image2, from '<PATH>/surface_30///img_000%01d.jpeg':

  Duration: 00:00:00.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A

    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), gray(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 6737x4869 [SAR 1:1 DAR 6737:4869], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc

Stream mapping:

  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4))

Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

Output #0, avi, to '<PATH>/surface_30///surface_30.avi':

  Metadata:

    ISFT            : Lavf58.29.100

    Stream #0:0: Video: msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4) (MP43 / 0x3334504D), yuv420p, 6737x4869 [SAR 1:1 DAR 6737:4869], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbn, 10 tbc

    Metadata:

      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 msmpeg4

    Side data:

      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1

frame=    2 fps=0.0 q=8.0 size=    6662kB time=00:00:00.20 bitrate=272859.9kbits/s speed=0.334x    
frame=    3 fps=2.2 q=10.0 size=   10502kB time=00:00:00.30 bitrate=286764.2kbits/s speed=0.22x    
frame=    4 fps=1.9 q=12.3 size=   13574kB time=00:00:00.40 bitrate=277987.7kbits/s speed=0.19x    
frame=    4 fps=1.4 q=12.3 size=   13574kB time=00:00:00.40 bitrate=277987.7kbits/s speed=0.145x    
frame=    4 fps=1.4 q=12.3 Lsize=   13657kB time=00:00:00.40 bitrate=279702.3kbits/s speed=0.145x    
video:13652kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.041926%
```

detecting mjpeg format and similar, but more detailed format `gray(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 6737x4869 [SAR 1:1 DAR 6737:4869].`

What is the difference when switching input from jpeg to jp2?